# Setting arguments in docker-compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Hi I want to use the haproxy exporter provided here https://github.com/prometheus/haproxy_exporter in a docker container.

I am using `docker-compose`for managing containers and want to recreate this command:

```
$ docker run -p 9101:9101 prom/haproxy-exporter -haproxy.scrape-uri="http://user:pass@haproxy.example.com/haproxy?stats;csv"
```

in my docker-compose.yml.

I am not sure how to pass the argument, after viewing the docker-compose documentation I tried it like this:

```
  haproxy-exporter:
    image: prom/haproxy-exporter
    ports:
      - 9101:9101
    network_mode: "host"
    build:
      args:
        - haproxy.scrape-uri="http://user:pass@haproxy.example.com/haproxy?stats;csv"
```

But this gives me an `file is invalid` message because it requires a context with a build.

Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is already built and pulled from the hub (unless you have your own Dockerfile) so you don't need the build option. Instead, pass your arguments as the command since the image appears to use an entrypoint (if their Dockerfile only had a cmd option, then you'd need to also pass /bin/haproxy-exporter in your command):

```
 haproxy-exporter:
    image: prom/haproxy-exporter
    ports:
      - 9101:9101
    network_mode: "host"
    command: -haproxy.scrape-uri="http://user:pass@haproxy.example.com/haproxy?stats;csv"
```

Comment: Hm after a while I am getting:
`Can't scrape HAProxy: Get http://localhost/;csv: dial tcp: 127.0.0.1:80: getsockopt: connection refused source=haproxy_exporter.go:309` so it seems the argument is still not forwarded correctly

Comment: Ok I got it! the `-` before the argument was missing in your solution! :)